# Stop Highcharts from cropping the series line between points on the x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a series chart with the following properties...

- `series.lineWidth` is 2px
- Hidden x-axis with `xAxis.lineWidth` set to 0

If two adjacent points happen to have a y-axis value of zero, and thus drawn along where the x-axis *would* be, the line drawn between them is 1px wide instead of 2px. Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1687), and [subsequent commit](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/ce759da361edbd70ed9570864b52f7fa27626f64), this seems like intended behavior. Is there a way to override this and always draw a 2px wide series line?

I can understand that on a chart with an x-axis, this could increase legibility, but in a chart without an x-axis, this looks more like a rendering error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could prevent the series from being clipped/cropped by setting [`series.clip`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.clip) to `false`.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [0, 0, 0, 4, 2],
    lineWidth: 2,
    clip: false
  }],
  xAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0
  },
  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s6gf92ou/1/)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I can't find this property anywhere in their docs. Neither http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series nor http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line> make any mention of it. Even a search for clip brings back nothing. How did you find this?

Comment: @Colin It is a option supported for internal use only, not part of official API, so it might get changed in next release without any info. Also, it will break zooming - http://jsfiddle.net/zkgmts5h/1/ I found this in [code](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js).